# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a widget that fetches the menu from my shopify store using the shopify_storefront 0.0.3 package.

I'm learning to code apps in Flutter with Dart but have not gotten to solve this error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.

Since I'm new to this I would appreciate it if you can give me an easily understandable answer on how to fix this error.

Thanks in advance!

Here in the second line I get the error

```
List<dynamic>? edges = List.from(
    data?['shop']['navigation']['mainMenu']['links']['edges'] ?? [], // Here I get the error.
  ) as List<dynamic>?;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [];

  for (var edge in edges!) {
    var item = edge['node'];
    items.add({
      'title': item['label'],
      'type': item['type'],
      'url': item['url'],
      'id': item['object']['id'],
    });
```

This is the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:root/global_singleton.dart';
import 'package:shopify_storefront/shopify_storefront.dart';

class MenuWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MenuWidgetState createState() => _MenuWidgetState();
}

class _MenuWidgetState extends State<MenuWidget> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> menuItems = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchMenuItems();
  }

  void fetchMenuItems() async {
    String query = '''
    query {
      shop {
        name
        navigation {
          mainMenu: linklists(title: "main-menu") {
            links(first: 10) {
              edges {
                node {
                  label
                  type
                  url
                  object {
                    ... on Product {
                      id
                    }
                    ... on Collection {
                      id
                    }
                    ... on Page {
                      id
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ''';

    var data = await GlobalSingleton().shopifyStoreFront?.fetchDataFromShopify(
          'Mystore',
          query as Function,
        );

    // Extract the necessary data into separate variables
    List<dynamic>? edges = List.from(
    data?['shop']['navigation']['mainMenu']['links']['edges'] ?? [],
  ) as List<dynamic>?;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [];

  for (var edge in edges!) {
    var item = edge['node'];
    items.add({
      'title': item['label'],
      'type': item['type'],
      'url': item['url'],
      'id': item['object']['id'],
    });
  }

    setState(() {
      menuItems = items;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: menuItems.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(menuItems[index]['title']),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried everything. I'd appreciate a solution that has worked for you and how it would look like in the context of my code.